# Calculator: fix delete button

Tags: javascript, calculator

I  am unable to understand how to code the javascript for the button which delete the recent character from display of the calculator.

When I try to do by this way `length - 1` it deletes all my values written in display of the calculator and displays me random number or `undefined`.

```js
let string = '';
// let Delete = document.getElementsByClassName('del');
let screen = document.getElementById('screen');
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

function del() {
  screen.value = screen.value.length - 1;
}
Array.from(buttons).forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.innerHTML == '=') {
      string = eval(string);
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    } else if (e.target.innerHTML == 'C') {
      string = "";
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    } else if (e.target.innerHTML == 'Del') {
      string = del();
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    } else {
      console.log(e.target)
      string = string + e.target.innerHTML;
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
<style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Macondo&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Macondo', cursive;
  border: 1px solid rgb(220, 255, 48);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-top: 53px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-h {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 2px solid rgb(141, 237, 52);
  background: rgb(54, 254, 54);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: -2px;
}

.button,
.del {
  padding: 18px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(252, 255, 89);
  box-shadow: 5px rgb(126, 122, 122);
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* .bg-red{ */


/* background-color: red; */


/* } */

.row {
  margin: 8px 0px;
}

.row input {
  padding: 15px 9px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 17px;
  font-size: 19px;
  background-color: rgb(205, 255, 145);
}

#last {
  margin-left: 13px;
}

#first-row {
  font-size: 1px;
  width: 285px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.first {
  margin: auto;
}

#M+,
#M- {
  width: 54px;
}

button #m,
#c-2,
#del,
#c-4,
#add,
#div,
#mult {
  background-color: rgb(255, 188, 2);
}

#eval {
  width: 122px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(53, 137, 255);
}

#C {
  background-color: rgb(255, 42, 0);
}

#mult {
  width: 53px;
}

#div {
  width: 51px;
}

.container {
  background-color: rgb(121, 255, 100);
  padding: 24px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    width: 324px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 17px;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
}

</style>
```

```html
<h1 class="text-h">Welcome To My Calculator !</h1>
<div class="container m-a mw-20 flex flex-col bg-red">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="screen" class="input" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div id="first-row" class="row first">
    <button id="C" class="button">C</button>
    <button id="c-2" class="button">%</button>
    <button id="del" class="button">Del</button>
    <button id="c-4" class="button">-</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="button">7</button>
    <button class="button">8</button>
    <button class="button">9</button>
    <button id="mult" class="button">*</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="button">4</button>
    <button class="button">5</button>
    <button class="button">6</button>
    <button id="div" class="button">/</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="button">1</button>
    <button class="button">2</button>
    <button class="button">3</button>
    <button id="add" class="button">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row right">
    <button class="button">0</button>
    <button class="button">.</button>
    <button id="eval" class="button">=</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string = string.slice(0, -1);` for it. It will delete last character that is entered.

That way you don't even need `del()` method.

See the code below:

```js
let string = '';
// let Delete = document.getElementsByClassName('del');
let screen = document.getElementById('screen');
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

Array.from(buttons).forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.innerHTML == '=') {
      string = eval(string);
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    } else if (e.target.innerHTML == 'C') {
      string = "";
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    } else if (e.target.innerHTML == 'Del') {
      string = string.slice(0, -1);
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    } else {
      console.log(e.target)
      string = string + e.target.innerHTML;
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
<style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Macondo&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Macondo', cursive;
  border: 1px solid rgb(220, 255, 48);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-top: 53px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-h {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  border: 2px solid rgb(141, 237, 52);
  background: rgb(54, 254, 54);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: -2px;
}

.button,
.del {
  padding: 18px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(252, 255, 89);
  box-shadow: 5px rgb(126, 122, 122);
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* .bg-red{ */


/* background-color: red; */


/* } */

.row {
  margin: 8px 0px;
}

.row input {
  padding: 15px 9px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 17px;
  font-size: 19px;
  background-color: rgb(205, 255, 145);
}

#last {
  margin-left: 13px;
}

#first-row {
  font-size: 1px;
  width: 285px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.first {
  margin: auto;
}

#M+,
#M- {
  width: 54px;
}

button #m,
#c-2,
#del,
#c-4,
#add,
#div,
#mult {
  background-color: rgb(255, 188, 2);
}

#eval {
  width: 122px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(53, 137, 255);
}

#C {
  background-color: rgb(255, 42, 0);
}

#mult {
  width: 53px;
}

#div {
  width: 51px;
}

.container {
  background-color: rgb(121, 255, 100);
  padding: 24px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    width: 324px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 17px;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
}

</style>
```

```html
<h1 class="text-h">Welcome To My Calculator !</h1>
<div class="container m-a mw-20 flex flex-col bg-red">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="screen" class="input" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div id="first-row" class="row first">
    <button id="C" class="button">C</button>
    <button id="c-2" class="button">%</button>
    <button id="del" class="button">Del</button>
    <button id="c-4" class="button">-</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="button">7</button>
    <button class="button">8</button>
    <button class="button">9</button>
    <button id="mult" class="button">*</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="button">4</button>
    <button class="button">5</button>
    <button class="button">6</button>
    <button id="div" class="button">/</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="button">1</button>
    <button class="button">2</button>
    <button class="button">3</button>
    <button id="add" class="button">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row right">
    <button class="button">0</button>
    <button class="button">.</button>
    <button id="eval" class="button">=</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! bro.. I was stuck at this thing but you solved my issue ...

Comment: @JaydeepDeshpande I'm glad this answer helped you. If it is good answer, please upvote and accept it, so other people can use it as a reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
function del(){
    screen.value = screen.value.length - 1;
}
```

The code inside the  above function del() is just decrementing the length of the string by 1.

What is supposed to be done here is slicing the string by removing the last character from the string whenever del button is clicked.

And the reason of displaying 'undefined' is that the del() function is not returning any value to the function call.

So the below code helps while using del() function:

```
function del(){
    screen.value = screen.value.slice(0, -1);
    console.log(`Screen Value : ${screen.value}`)
    return screen.value;
}
```

But we do not need del() function as well.

```
string = string.slice(0, -1);
document.querySelector("input").value = string;
```

The above lines can do our work.

Please refer to the complete script below.

```
    let string = "";
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
    
    Array.from(buttons).forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            if (e.target.innerHTML == "=") {
                string = eval(string);
                document.querySelector("input").value = string;
            } else if (e.target.innerHTML == "C") {
                string = "";
                document.querySelector("input").value = string;
            } else if (e.target.innerHTML == "Del") {
                string = string.slice(0, -1);
                document.querySelector("input").value = string;
            } else {
                console.log(e.target);
                string = string + e.target.innerHTML;
                document.querySelector("input").value = string;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let screen = document.querySelector("input");
      let clean = document.querySelector(".clean");
      

      function bton(btval) {
        screen.value += btval;
      };

      clean.onclick = function () {
      screen.value = "";
      };
      function equalbt() {
        if(screen.value===""){
          screen.value="";
        }
        else{
         var txt = screen.value;
         var result = eval(txt);
         screen.value = result;
      };
      };
      function del() {
        screen.value = screen.value.slice(0, -1);
        txt= screen.value;
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster+Two:wght@400;700&display=swap");

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lobster Two",cursive;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #8a8a8a 0%, #ba8f2b 40%, #30ff10 100%);
}
.calculator {
  border: 1px solid #d9d1d8;
  border-radius: 14px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 5px #ff1084;
  background: transparent;
}
input {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align-last: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
::placeholder {
  color: #000;
}
button {
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 1px -5px 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
.eq {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.oper {
  background-color: #f83b02;
  color: #ecf4e0;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.del,.clean{
  font-weight: 900;
  background: #f90834;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="calculator">
      <div class="screen">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="bt">
        <button class="clean">ac</button>
        <button class="del" onclick="del()">del</button>
        <button class="oper" onclick="bton('.')">.</button>
        <button class="oper" onclick="bton('-')">-</button>

      </div>
      <div class="bt">
        <button onclick="bton(7)">7</button>
        <button onclick="bton(8)">8</button>
        <button onclick="bton(9)">9</button>
        
        <button class="oper"onclick="bton('*')">x</button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bt">
        <button onclick="bton(6)">6</button>
        <button onclick="bton(5)">5</button>
        <button onclick="bton(4)">4</button>
      <button class="oper"onclick="bton('/')">/</button>
      </div>
      <div class="bt">
        <button onclick="bton(1)">1</button>
        <button onclick="bton(2)">2</button>
        <button onclick="bton(3)">3</button>
        <button  class="oper"onclick="bton('+')">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="bt">
        <button onclick="bton(0)">0</button>
        <button onclick="bton(00)">00</button>
        <button class="oper eq" onclick="equalbt('=')">=</button>
       
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While it looks nicer, I don't understand what your answer adds to the already provided ones?